# Replace id name in $('id').val(); with variable name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and am trying to use a variable to make it constantly update for every item i have in my list.
Is there a way to do this?

```
 function AddToCart(clicked_id) {
   var Name = clicked_id;     //Sets Name variable to the id of the clicked item
   var QtyName = Name +'Qty';     //Updates quantity name to that of clicked item
   var QtyVal = $(#QtyName).val();     //Gets value of the quantity of the item
   alert(Name);
   alert(QtyName);
   alert(QtyVal);
   Cookies.set(QtyName , QtyVal);     //Sets cookie to (Name of the quantity variable, Quantity Value)
 }
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: change `$(#QtyName).val();` to `$('#'+QtyName).val();`

Comment: glad to help mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter passed to the jQuery function is just a string.  So you'd concatenate string values just like you do on the line exactly before that.  So if you concatenate a string like this:

```
'#' + QtyName
```

Then you'd pass exactly that to the jQuery function:

```
$('#' + QtyName)
```

Comment: closing a typo OP is better than answering